# TimeSeries prediction / optimization problem for a solar powered water pump

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I would like to solve an "optimization problem" by using new and fancy machine learning methods (also to learn more about them) and I haven't found yet which methods / models will help me to solve my specific problem. May be you have some inspiration or hints :-)

**Constraints:**

A water pump is connected to a battery which is powered by a solar panel.
The water pump speed can be set from 0 (stop) to 1023 (running at full speed).
The battery can be charged up to 13.4 V and it is empty at 11.7 V.
I can measure the battery voltage and current and set the pump speed by using an ESP8266.

**Goal:**

From e.g. 8 am until 10 pm, the pump speed should always be as high as possible.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the battery capacity is limited and the sun is not always shining (for the solar panel). So on a sunny day, the pump can run at e.g. speed 500 from 8am - 10pm but if it is cloudy the speed should be slower to consume less power. If it is cloudy in the morning it should run at slow speed in the morning and if it gets sunny in the afternoon it can run a little bit faster and so on.

**Solution / TL;DR:**

I have the following inputs to train e.g. a Long short-term memory (LSTM) artificial recurrent neural network (RNN):

- timestamp (will measure the values every 60sec)
- battery voltage [11.7-13.4]
- pump speed (will drain the battery) [0-1023]
- luminance (will charge the battery) [0 (dark) - 1023 (bright)]

Now I thought of using a genetic algorithm to calculate the "optimal pump speed plan" for the day at 8 am:

e.g. 08:00 -> 300, 08:01 -> 300, ... , 10:00 -> 400, ..., 15:00 -> 900, ..., 22:00 -> 0

As I don't know if such a plan (with random pump speed values) would actually work I would like to predict the battery voltage by using the RNN as it has learned on the data history, that high luminance will charge the battery and high pump speed will drain the battery faster.

So I have the pump speed for the next 24h and a weather forecast for the luminance and now the RNN should predict the battery voltage. **How can this be achieved?** Is a LSTM the right tool?

Then I can check the battery voltage if it always stays > 11.7V (the fitness function), if not, I can update the plan accordingly (crossover / mutation) until the genetic algorithm found a good plan.

I can also redo the whole calculation and adapt the plan every 60min.

What do you think?

Here is the already measured data for ~2 (sunny) days. Pump is turned on (1023) for 10 minutes every hour. When the battery is full > 13.4V the voltage starts "flickering" by the solar charger controller; I guess this would confuse the RNN and I could apply: if value > 13.4 ? 13.4 : value.

[image: data example]

Thanks
Ben